# Data missing JSONDecoder

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, decodable, jsondecoder

I am trying to load an array of `JSON` dictionaries into an object with swift using `Alamofire` and `SwiftyJSON`, but when the data is downloaded, I get the error:

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "inProrgresss", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"inProrgresss\", intValue: nil) (\"inProrgresss\").", underlyingError: nil)).

The localised description just says that the data is missing.  My JSON is [here](https://m.cubecomps.com/api/v1/competitions/) and my code is like this:

```
struct CompData: Codable {
    let inProrgresss: [[String: String]]
    let past: [[String: String]]
    let upcoming: [[String: String]]
}

func getData(url: URLConvertible) {
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (dataResponse) in
        if dataResponse.result.value != nil {
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            let JSONVar = JSON(dataResponse.result.value)
            let data = Data(dataResponse.data!)
            print(data)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
                let newData = try decoder.decode(CompData.self, from: data)
                print("NEWDATA \(newData)")
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            print(JSONVar)
        }
    }
}
```

I am quite new to converting JSON into datatypes, and I couldn't find anything on here that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please **read** the JSON. There is no key `inProrgresss`.

And create a struct for the dictionaries, it's pretty straightforward

```
struct CompData: Decodable {
    let inProgress: [Location]?
    let past: [Location]
    let upcoming: [Location]
}

struct Location : Decodable {
    let city, countryCode, name, date, country, id : String
}
```

And declare `inProgress` as optional because the array is empty.

**Edit**:

There is a lot of redundant code in `getData`. This is more efficient. `convertFromSnakeCase` does what it says.

```
func getData(url: URLConvertible) {
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    Alamofire.request(url).responseData { (response) in
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let data):
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            do {
                let result = try decoder.decode(CompData.self, from: data)
                print("NEWDATA \(result)")
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        case .failure(let error): print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yes... but will that now convert it do an array of dictionaries, or is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Yes it will, but it's more convenient to create structs as well for the other dictionaries

Comment: Ok - so just repeat the struct thing and it'll do it automatically or do I need to change the getData code?